# Apache http client 4.5 form authentication failing returns same login-page

Tags: java, httpclient

I'm writing a login-sequence where I

- authenticate
- click on (get) request to particular resource

The website uses form-based authentication.

**Code**

```
package bdd;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.RequestBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCookieStore;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.LaxRedirectStrategy;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;



public class bdd {
    
    public bdd() {
        super();
    }
            
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        
        // CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
         
                 //Creating the RequestBuilder object
         CloseableHttpClient instance =
    HttpClientBuilder.create().setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();
         
         
         RequestBuilder reqbuilder = RequestBuilder.post();

         //Setting URI and parameters
         RequestBuilder reqbuilder1 = reqbuilder.setUri("https://abc.ai");
         RequestBuilder reqbuilder2 = reqbuilder1.addParameter("user_id", 
            "user_password").addParameter("abc", "abc");

         //Building the HttpUriRequest object
         HttpUriRequest httppost = reqbuilder2.build();

         //Executing the request
         HttpResponse httpresponse = instance.execute(httppost);
             
         //Printing the status and the contents of the response
         System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity()));
         System.out.println(httpresponse.getStatusLine());
      }
   }
```

**Issues**

1. I'm received by same page(login) I can verify that password didn't went through because of following response html body which say
    `<div class="form-group"> <input type="password" autocomplete="off" class="form-control rounded-0" name="user_password" placeholder="Password" required="" value=""> </div>`

**html**

```
<body class="h-100 bg-white">
    <div class="container-fluid h-100">
        <div class="row h-100">
            <div class="align-items-center bg-white col-3 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <div class="mt-3 mb-5">
                        <img src="data:image/png;base64,c/PIhPjXeSSysNrs2gNQvDzaVBT1f/bu652Pz51g4UkpEpkbCtH3YugBoZQmCC">
                    </div>
                    <div id="errorMsg" class="alert alert-danger text-center d-none"></div>
                    <form id="loginForm" action="/login" method="post" onsubmit="_checkSubmit()">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control rounded-0" name="user_id" placeholder="Username" required="" autofocus="" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" autocomplete="off" class="form-control rounded-0" name="user_password" placeholder="Password" required="" value="">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn btn-block rounded-pill">Login</button>
                    </form>
                    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-center text-muted">© 2018-2020</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>if(!location.port&&"https"!==location.protocol){if(-1===location.href.indexOf("https://")){location.href=location.href.replace("http:","https:")}}var errorMsg=document.getElementById("errorMsg");if("?credentials=invalid"===location.search){errorMsg.classList.remove("d-none");errorMsg.innerHTML="Username and Password do not match."}else if("?error=request"===location.search){errorMsg.classList.remove("d-none");errorMsg.innerHTML="Problem with REST API. Contact Admin"}function _checkSubmit(){var user_id=window.document.forms.loginForm.user_id.value,user_password=window.document.forms.loginForm.user_password.value;gtag("event","loginAttempt",{event_category:user_id,event_label:user_password})}</script>

    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-97985973-5"></script>
    <script>window.dataLayer=window.dataLayer||[];function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)}gtag("js",new Date);gtag("config","UA-97985973-5");</script>



</body>
```

I'm suppose to land on landing-page which is different from html source code (snippet) provided above.

2. Do i need to set-up cookies in headers too, I'm not sure if authorization header is set by httpclient object or no.

I think my post request is not correctly formatted, I appreciate some help here.

**edit**

I edited the code with

```
 BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
           BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("JSESSIONID", "1234");
           cookie.setDomain(".abc.ai");
           cookie.setPath("/login");
           cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
           
          
         CloseableHttpClient instance =
    HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore).setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();
```

but results are same i'm still hitting the login page

Comment: i added the html code also

Comment: So are you submitting to the /login path that the form is submitting to? Doesn't look like it from the code you posted.

Comment: Almost a week no feedback. Was it simply the problem of posting to the wrong path?